# How would I write to the database when a button is clicked in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am working on a **simple** **eCommerce** **site** in Rails, and I am having a little trouble trying to figure out **how I would place an item** in a basket **when its clicked**. **I have a table** for where I want the items to go. I am working with **rails 4** and I am pretty new to Rails.

**View For listing items:**

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <div data-role="content" >
       <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <a href="#bar"data-rel="dialog"></a>
      <li data-icon="plus"><a href="#">
        <img src=<%= item.item_media.url %> />
        <h3><%= item.brand %> </h3>
        <p><%= item.short_description %> </p></a>
        <a href="#">Example</a> <!--This is the button that is suppose to save the item.-->
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer will depend on exactly how you want to do it. Here's the key thing, in my opinion: in order for this to work, there are a few components that will have to work together. You'll have a model involved, a controller, I assume some ajax, some view code...it's a lot of stuff. So the key thing is to get the lowest-level thing to work, then add the layer on top of that.

So first, write a test for adding an item to the basket, not through the UI but just through Ruby. I don't know if you're writing this from scratch or using a third-party tool or what, but I'd probably start there either way.

Next I'd make sure you have a controller that can call your model code or third-party tool code or whatever to add an item to the basket.

Once you have your controller working (preferably with a test for your controller code), you can call that controller code via a link or an ajax call or whatever you want.

Hopefully that way of breaking it down makes the problem a little more approachable.

Comment: But one question, I know with a form you can get the details of what is being submitted by using the params method, but how would you get the item that is being submitted if they are only clicking a button and not inserting the information via form?

Comment: If using a link, you could pass the item's id in the query string. If using ajax, you could pass the id in the ajax call's "data".

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new in this ROR world and I'm now writing my first real world application
If there is something I learned in the past few weeks is that ROR is really great, why?

Because of GEMS

I think that at least in the beginning it is great to have such arsenal of resources and tools  and you can learn a lot from it

So, I suggest you to look at some eCommerce gems - I think that the best one out there is Spree (http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html) and just integrate it into your project

It will save you a lot of time

Enjoy